# CSRF token mismatch issue when deployed 2 same laravel project on the one server

Tags: laravel, deployment, csrf-token

I have a Laravel project working on my server with my-domain.com perfectly.
I want to upgrade it to beta version, but won't reflect it to live until complete upgrade.

So I setup subdomain(ex: `dev.my-domain.com`) and copied my project to another directory, link it to subdomain.

After copied the existing project to new directory, I cleared the cache & cookie, sessions.

The second project display with sub-domain but the problem is that when I try to login I'm getting an error "*CSRF token mismatch*".

[image]

> Note: When setting up a subdomain, I set the subdomain to point to the IP address of my server.
> So my main domain & sub-domain point to the same IP address for now.

The existing site is working perfectly, and if I replaced the directory name connected to the subdomain with the directory name of the existing site for testing, the new cloned project worked perfectly as the original my-domain.

I tried to set the cookie & path as different in "`config/session.php`" file but it not solved my problem.

This is driving me crazy.
I did some research and looked at similar issues, but I couldn't find a solution that exactly matched my problem.
Does someone have any ideas on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In config/session.php change your app name in this part: 'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'yoursite'), '_').'_session'
    ), ---- and set sub domain url in env file

Comment: Yes. I changed APP_NAME to different name, and set APP_URL to my sub-domain as well, But not working.

Comment: I'm not sure but if it is a temporary app on your subdomain maybe protected $addHttpCookie = false; in app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php will work.

Comment: I just tested, but not working, got same error. I tried to disable VerifyCsrfToken middlware in the Kenal.php for web routes, In this case I didn't get CSRF token error but It redirect to login page again after loggedin for some reason.

Comment: Because in your layouts app.blade.php by default included meta tag csrf token.

Comment: hmm. I disabled meta tag & insert `$addHttpCookie = false;` into VerifyCsfrToken.php. But not working, same error.
Btw, I don't want to disable CSRF token because it contains a lot of sensitive information even this is dev version. I would like to find a right solution. 
Thank you for your attention)))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257011/discussion-between-web-star-and-ehf-shahab).

Comment: You Copy paste it may be this causing the issue .env -- "APP_KEY=" -- Try Regenerating it .

Comment: Clear browser cookies/session data after changing the app name. Also `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Yes. I did all them, Clear cache/cookie/sessions, also re-generated APP_KEY. It's very weird

Comment: Could this be because of CORS policy?